# Detailed example of RxJs concatMap to get a user ID, then query a user with it

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, concatmap

Having trouble getting concatMap to make the first query for a user id and then use the id for a second query.

This is how how the docs explain its usage but examples demonstrating this working don't seem to exist.

```
this.authenticationService.currentUser.pipe(
    concatMap((principal: Principal) => {
        this.getUser(principal.id: String)
    })
).subscribe((user: User) => {
    console.log(user);
});
```

This is all red in VSC.

```
[ts]
Argument of type '(principal: Principal) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: Principal, index: number) => ObservableInput<{}>'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<{}>'. [2345]
(parameter) principal: Principal
```

Can someone help me make sense of this?
I believe it may be because of TS 2.7+ no null returns checking.

Comment: Thats telling you that you need to return from `cancatMap()`. Do ` return this.getUser(principal.id: String)`

Comment: Fat arrows have implicit returns and automatically are returning `this.getUser(principal.id: String)`

Comment: They have implicit return if you don't add `"{" ... "}"` . So your code should be `concatMap((principal: Principal) => this.getUser(principal.id: String))`

Comment: Awesome yes, I've tried that and the original error is gone (queries working). Now I believe TS' 'no null checks' are blowing it up because `principle.id` is undefined until the first return. Thanks for following through and helping.

Comment: You are welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

`this.getUser(principal.id: String)` doesn't seems to be valid typescript syntax, try `this.getUser(principal.id as string)`; if type `Principal` has `{id: string}` definition, then just use `this.getUser(principal.id)`

Answer (score 0):

```
this.getUser(principal.id: String)
```

Is an invalid way to call a function, you only define the type of your parameter in the definition of the function parameters, not when calling the function.

It should be

```
this.getUser(principal.id)
```

Also your function does not return anything.

```
(principal: Principal) => {
  this.getUser(principal.id: String)
}
```

Returns void, you either need

```
(principal: Principal) => this.getUser(principal.id)
```

or

```
(principal: Principal) => {
  return this.getUser(principal.id: String)
}
```